# dotnet restore not using PackageReference condition

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, dotnet-cli, dotnet-restore

my project has multiple target frameworks, 2 of the package reference need to use a different version for .net461

[image]

when building in VS 2017 everything works and the dependency shows using the right versions.

[image]

but when build using dotnet cli, the dependency shows the wrong version is being use for .net461.  is this a bug in dotnet cli?

[image]

I also try putting those 2 pkg in another ItemGroup tag with condition but still the same

update: for anyone else running in to this issue, I ended up using `<Choose>` with `<when>` condition to fix this.. so look something like this.

```
  <Choose>
<When Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="105.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
<When Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451' ">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="105.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="7.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
<Otherwise>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Otherwise>
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this?