# Package reference not restored with Condition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-devops, yaml

I have a private NuGet package that I only want to use when the configuration is set to something other then 'Debug', otherwise I want to use my referenced DLL's.

The solution to this is:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Reference Include="Foo">
               <HintPath>My_DLL.dll</HintPath>
            </Reference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Foo" Version="0.1" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

In Visual Studio, when I switch the Configuration from Release to Debug and vice versa this works.

The problem is when I let the buildserver restore and build this.
It seems that `dotnet restore -f /p:Configuration=Release` does not include my packagereference, yet when I add those same packages to the `<ItemGroup>` where other packages are, the buildserver correctly restores the private NuGet package.

Question is, how can I let the build(server) resolve my NuGets, just as Visual Studio does?

Note: not the same as [dotnet restore not using PackageReference condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485020/dotnet-restore-not-using-packagereference-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused by `dotnet restore`. It restores the (nuget) dependencies and (nuget) tools of a project. Both dependencies and tools should be contained in nuget packages. Basically the command uses nuget.exe to complete the process.
I would go with the following approach for the csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Debug' ">
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.12" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Reference Include="log4net">
      <HintPath>..\FileRefs\log4netlocal.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The project structure:

```
CustomItemGroupSolution
│   CustomItemGroup.sln
│
├───CustomItemGroup
│       CustomItemGroup.csproj
│       CustomItemGroup.csproj.user
│       Program.cs
│
└───FileRefs
        log4netlocal.dll
```

For the build the following commands will do the proper work:

```sh
    dotnet build -c Release
    dotnet build -c Debug
```